# How to validate objects before insert/update/delete using mybatis on dao layer

Tags: java, mybatis

I use mybatis, and want do domain validate on dao layer. 
So, Is there a recommended way to validate objects before insert/update/delete?
Typical validations I would like to do is check sizes and make sure the column uses one of the allowed values before the insert/update.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your model with constraint annotations from *javax.validation.constraints*, 
*org.hibernate.validator.constraints*, ...

And execute the validation javax.validation.Validator#validate(param). You have to inject the validator (depending on your environment).

To check against allowed values, annotate with your own *javax.validation.Constraint* annotation.

Comment: I want to know, where to execute the validation, while there is no daoImpl file when use mybatis

Comment: Validation is not DAO's job anyway. It must be called before. Depending on the kind of application you run, it can even be called by the container just by annotating.

Comment: in my mind, i would validate business logical on service layer and field check on dao layer.the point here is, there is no daoImpl class when using mybatis. if they have, i usually validate domain there.